# error column cannot be null, trying to upload file into sql

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, express

i am still new in node js, and i am trying to make some backend with file upload/ image upload function that can be stored in sql, i am trying using multer but it cant read my file while testing in postman body. anybody can help me where i do wrong?
here is my controller

```
const { db } = require('./db');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');


const getgambar = (req, res) => {
const sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM gambar";

  db.query(sqlQuery, (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      res.send(result);
      console.log(result);
    }
  });
};

const addgambar = (req,res) => {
    
    const idimg = req.body.idimg;
    const gambar = req.file.gambar;

    console.log()
    
    const sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO image (idimg,gambar) VALUE (?,?)";
    
    db.query(sqlQuery, [idimg,gambar], (err, result) => {
      if (err) {
        res.send({
            message: "error",
            err
        })
      } else {
        res.send({
            message: "YES"
        })
      }
    });

};
module.exports = {
    getgambar,
    addgambar,
};
```

here is my route

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const multer = require('multer');
const path = require('path');
const ctrl = require('./gambarctrl');

const storange = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: './uploads',
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        return cb(null, `${file.fieldname}_${Date.now()}${path.extname(file.originalname)}`)
    }
})

const upload = multer({
    storange: storange
})

router.get('/image/display', ctrl.getgambar)
router.post('/image',upload.single('gambar'), ctrl.addgambar)

module.exports = router;
```

and here my index

```
const { db } = require('./db');
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();
const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload');
const gambarroute = require ('./gambarroute');
const multer = require('multer');



app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use(gambarroute);

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('on port 3000!');
  });
```

i am still quite new in node js and i am still searching for tutorial, i appriciate for the help.

Comment: What DBMS are you using (eg MySQL, PostgreSQL, etc) and what library are you using to connect to it and execute queries?

Comment: i am using mysql with aa php admin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems here...

1. Multer puts the single uploaded [file](https://github.com/expressjs/multer#file-information) into `req.file` so you should use

   ```js
   const gambar = req.file; // no `.gambar`
   ```
2. Assuming your DB column is a `BLOB` or `BINARY` type, you need to [provide a `Buffer`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#buffer).

   Since you're storing the images within the DB, you don't need to use `DiskStorage`. Use `MemoryStorage` instead which provides a `Buffer` out-of-the-box

```js
const upload = multer({
  storage: multer.memoryStorage(), // watch your spelling
})
```

Then bind the `.buffer` property in your query.

```js
db.query(sqlQuery, [idimg, gambar.buffer], (err, result) => {
  // ...
});
```

---

To respond with the image from Express, use something like this

```js
router.get("/image/display/:id", (req, res, next) => {
  db.query(
    "SELECT `gambar` FROM `image` WHERE `idimg` = ?",
    [req.params.id],
    (err, results) => {
      if (err) {
        return next(err);
      }

      if (!results.length) {
        return res.sendStatus(404);
      }

      // set the appropriate content type
      res.set("Content-Type", "image/jpg");
      res.send(results[0].gambar);
    }
  );
});
```

and from the frontend...

```html
<img src="http://localhost:3000/image/display/some-id" />
```

Comment: thanks, it solved the problem. but may i ask question ? what is BLOB type? and how to show the image/file if the DB column is BLOB? i am trying to use get all data and it show the some like random text in it.
i am sorry for asking some question again. but thank you for helping me solving the problem.

Comment: _"what is BLOB type"_... see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/blob.html. I'll update my answer with an example of responding with an image buffer

Comment: thank you for the answer, i have some question regarding those display code, what the meading about the content type? and the image/jpg is if jpg only extention or something different?

Comment: oh and it is normal when i try it with postman it still show text like "????JFIF??C    $.' ",#(7),01444'9=82<.342??C  2!!22222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222???"????M !1AQaq?"2???R?"
is this normal?

Comment: No, Postman should be able to show an image. TBH, I wouldn't recommend storing images in your DB. Store them in the filesystem and save the path in the DB

Comment: i see so that is not normal. is there a way to make it appear in like site when it deployed with frontend? and to store the path it use diskStorange function, rename it and insert it into DB or there is another way?